# Bootstrap row with one column breaking out of the boxed container

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4

I am building a layout with bootstrap. In the design most of the elements are boxed (so I use the "container" class).

Some rows have 1 column that is inside the container but 1 other column that needs to break out of the container and be full width.

Here is an image of what I want to achieve:
[image]

I really struggle to create that layout. Any ideas?
Here is a codepen of the code below: https://codepen.io/leonfrombeawwwer/pen/bXGvQb

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-6">
          <div class="green-box"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="blue-box"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.green-box {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.blue-box {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}
```

I tried a container-fluid container with percentage width for the one column that needs to stay inside in boxed layout. But that pushes all the other elements f.e. header navigation too.

I also tried absolute positioning and played with flexbox. Nothing ended up in a result that is useful in all viewports.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add an image of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: That is a great idea, thanks. :) Did add it above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution now. Please find it in that codepen: `[https://codepen.io/leonfrombeawwwer/pen/bXGvQb][1]`
[[https://codepen.io/leonfrombeawwwer/pen/bXGvQb][1](https://codepen.io/leonfrombeawwwer/pen/bXGvQb)](https://codepen.io/leonfrombeawwwer/pen/bXGvQb)

or here:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="container-fluid relative-container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 placeholder"></div>
    <div class="col-6">
          <div class="green-box absolute-full-width-image"></div>
        </div>
   </div> <!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .container-fluid .relative-container -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="blue-box"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 placeholder"></div>
  </div> <!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

```
.green-box {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.blue-box {
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 120%;
}

.relative-container {
  position relative;
}

.absolute-full-width-image {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 110%;
}
```